# Maximum update depth exceeded. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops. Maybe Firebase has been updated now

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Maybe Firebase has been updated now that's why I'm having this error. I can't integrate Firebase into my project because I'm using the previous format to integrate Firebase into my project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgwV5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb2Wj.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: The code in the image doesn't seem related to the issue. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the relevant code you've an issue with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.